# pandas reshape long based on prefixes

Tags: python, pandas, reshape, data-cleaning

I have a Pandas dataframe with the following columns

```
game_id, date, country, winner_name, winner_age, ... winner_ranking, loser_name, loser_age, ... loser_ranking
1        1/2/10  UK .     Ben          21               12            Michael     22 .    13
```

I want to reshape it to have the following format

```
game_id, date, country, competitor, name, age, ranking 
 1       1/2/10 UK       winner    Ben    21   12
 1       1/2/10 UK       loser     Michael 22   13
```

I.e. for every column starting with a prefix 'winner_' or 'loser_', remove this prefix, and split the winner and loser into different rows. The list of winner and loser variables is quite long, so it's not that helpful if I have to hardcode.

Here's how I'm currently doing it, I'm wondering if there is a neater approach, for example using melt?

```
winner_df = combined_df.loc[:,[x for x in colnames if 'loser_' not in x]]
winner_df.columns = [c.replace('winner_','') for c in winner_df.columns]
winner_df['competitor'] = 'winner'
loser_df = combined_df.loc[:,[x for x in colnames if 'winner_' not in x]]
loser_df.columns = [c.replace('loser_','') for c in loser_df.columns]
loser_df['competitor'] = 'loser'
long_df = winner_df.append(loser_df,sort=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create `MultiIndex` from all columns without columns with splitter by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), then create `MultiIndex` in columns by [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and last reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and `rename` column:

```
df = df.set_index(['game_id','date','country'])

df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
df = df.stack(0).reset_index().rename(columns={'level_3':'competitor'})
print (df) 
   game_id    date country competitor  age     name  ranking
0        1  1/2/10      UK      loser   22  Michael       13
1        1  1/2/10      UK     winner   21      Ben       12
```